# Executing runtime code parameters

Tags: vb.net

The following is some code to execute code at runtime:

```
    Dim SourceCode As String = txtCode.Text

    Dim Dlls() As String = {"System.dll", "System.Core.dll", "System.Data.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll"} 'Any referenced dll's
    Dim Compiler As New VbCompiler(SourceCode, Dlls)
    Dim CodeAssembly As Assembly = Compiler.Compile
    If Compiler.Successful Then
        Dim instance As Object = CodeAssembly.CreateInstance("TestCode.Class1")
        Dim CodeType As Type = instance.GetType
        Dim Info As MethodInfo = CodeType.GetMethod("ShowMessage")
        Info.Invoke(instance, Nothing)
    Else
        For Each i As CompilerError In Compiler.Errors
            MsgBox(i.ErrorText)
        Next
    End If
```

txtCode.text =:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Namespace TestCode
    Class Class1
        Sub ShowMessage()
            MessageBox.Show("Test")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This works perfectly. I am wanting to know how to pass arguments to a function. ie

txtCode.text = :

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Namespace TestCode
    Class Class1
        Sub ShowMessage(ByVal x As String)
            MessageBox.Show(x)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I would like to run the 'ShowMessage" function with a string as the parameter, ("Test") for an example.

I am pretty sure it is at the following lines:

```
    Dim Info As MethodInfo = CodeType.GetMethod("ShowMessage")
    Info.Invoke(instance, Nothing)
```

But I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass string value.

```
 Info.Invoke(instance, New Object(){"Test"})
```

EDIT: Two arguments

```
 Info.Invoke(instance, New Object(){"First","Second"})
```

Comment: Sub ShowMessage(ByVal x As String)
            MessageBox.Show(x)
        End Sub

Comment: @SimonCanning - I'm sorry! do you want to say something? Have a look at Invoke() method's second argument. That way you can pass an argument to ShowMessage.